# How to use models from Django in C#?

Tags: c#, django

I use Django as backend and C# as frontend. Django provides serialization from models to json. My question is how to deserialize json data(which are serialized from Django) to C# classes?

Also, I found handling json in C# is not flexible, in contrast you can use dictionary to handle json in Python. Is there a good way to effectively handle json data in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used it in a long time, but [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) did this rather nicely, it's probably worth a try.

Example from the website:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```